# conditional display of data in asp.net mvc layout

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In an ASP.NEt MVC application, how is it possible to display some conditional data to a layout page?

My application allows a user with a role of "Admin" to view the other user's pages and data from the same application. When the Admin views the pages of another user he/she needs to see the information of the user like his name/role/etc whose data he/she is viewing ( this information comes from the DB) . This info needs to be shown in all the pages when an Admin User is logged in and ONLY when an ADmin is logged in. i.e, if a user who is not Admin enters these details should not be shown as it is not relevant.

The issue iam facing in my attempts is that the Admin user does not login to the user's page, instead I have to achieve this feature of switching to the users view by clicking on a list/grid of users. This takes me to the home page of the user (and i get the inforamtion displayed since i set it in viwbag) .Question is, how do i set this value in the subsequent user pages of this session. Trying to avoid filling this viewbag value in every controller/action.

Please help!

PS: The information that needs to be displayed in the layout is based on the user's ID that the Admin selects from the grid. It commes from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the user id to a cookie and use a action filter to check for this cookie on requests done by the admin user